# Run Ant script from Gradle

Tags: java, ant, gradle

I'm trying to run ant script from Gradle, but I have this exception:

```
  Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask was not found.
```

And I'd rather use ant-junit from local libs, but I do not know how, I am pretty new to Gradle.

I found this code

```
configurations { 
  antClasspath 
} 
dependencies { 
  antClasspath 'org.apache.ant:ant-junit4:1.8.3' 
} 
ClassLoader antClassLoader = org.apache.tools.ant.Project.class.classLoader 
configurations.antClasspath.each { File f -> 
  antClassLoader.addURL(f.toURI().toURL()) 
}
```

But I don not know what I have to change if the jar is already in mt lib folder. I do not want to use maven repo.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Gradle's [built-in support](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test) for running JUnit tests?

Comment: The pc I am running test does not have internet connection

Comment: I'm not sure how working offline is specifically keeping you from using Gradle's Test task. If you a referring dependency management then you can use [local libraries](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies) with Gradle.

Comment: maven tag wasn't be here

Comment: Running gradle without net connection may not be a very good idea. Nevertheless if You have the jar You need in the local directory, just add id to script dependencies using file dependencies. See: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#file-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

This is just repost from comment, which solved my problem: Thanks to [Opal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542270/opal)

Running gradle without net connection may not be a very good idea. Nevertheless if You have the jar You need in the local directory, just add id to script dependencies using file dependencies. See: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#file-dependencies from Opal

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the following Gradle error:

```
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> Problem: failed to create task or type junit
  Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask was not found.
          This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
  Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
          -ANT_HOME/lib
          -the IDE Ant configuration dialogs
```

by adding the following lines in my Ant script `build.xml` just before my Ant task `<junit>`

```
<taskdef name="junit"
  classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask"
  classpath="/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar"
/>
```

This is the full Ant target `test`:

```
<target name="test" depends="test_compile">
  <mkdir dir="${test.report.dir}" />

  <!-- Required for Gradle -->
  <taskdef name="junit"
  classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask"
  classpath="/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar"
  />

  <junit printsummary="yes" fork="true" haltonfailure="on">
      <classpath refid="classpath_test"/>
      <batchtest>
          <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}">
              <include name="**/*Tester.java" />
          </fileset>
      </batchtest>
  </junit>
</target>
```

The [answer about *"JUnitTask was not found"*](/a/9776251/938111) from [oers](/u/644450) has been a useful help to find my above fix.

## Identify the issue

To understand the issue, I have tweaked the scripts `build.xml` and `build.gradle` in order to compare the Ant and Gradle outputs. See also the [answer of *How to get “gradle” have similar output details as “ant”?*](/a/41442544/938111) for some details.

The interesting difference is in the `-classpath` parameter:

### Using Ant

```
/some/path/myApplication.jar
/usr/share/java/ant-launcher-1.9.7.jar
/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar
/usr/share/ant/lib/junit.jar
/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar
/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar
```

### Using Gradle

```
/some/path/myApplication.jar
/usr/lib/gradle/3.2.1/lib/ant-launcher-1.9.6.jar
/usr/lib/gradle/3.2.1/lib/ant-1.9.6.jar
```

### Difference

We can observe that Gradle uses its own `ant-launcher-1.9.6.jar` and `ant-1.9.6.jar`. But Gradle does not use the JARs from Ant installation (`/usr/share/ant/lib/*jar` are symbolic links to `/usr/share/java/*jar`).

## Long term

In [this discussion about integration of **Ant JUnit taskdef**](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/7517), Luke Daley confirms in Novembre 2013;

> Gradle uses its own 'instance' of ant and does not bother using what's installed at `$ANT_HOME`

In [this discussion about JUnit 5](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/19487) Eric Wendelin expressed the priority to integrate more JUnit within Gradle core.

Threfore, solution for long term is to stop using JUnit from Ant scripts and convert them into Gradle syntax.