# Gradle Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

Tags: java, gradle

is it possible to use local folder with jars in Gradle? It seems that it is looking in a correct folder, but it cannot find the jar, why?

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyProject'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':antClasspath'.
>   Could not find org.apache.ant:ant-junit4:1.9.4.
>            Searched in the following locations:

Comment: share your build.gradle to obtain an useful answer

Comment: I suppose this is the continuation of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000235/run-ant-script-from-gradle? Share build.gradle file.

Comment: oh, finally resolved, typo!!!